# Why I cannot store an image in SQLite database in Flask

Tags: python, sqlite

I spent 2 days trying to figure out how I can store an image in my 
SQLite database after I receive the image from a from in HTML page using Flask in python.

I did everythin I tried to convert it to binary using sqlite3.Binary(image) and then insert it to the database but I did not work.

this is a [recourse](http://www.numericalexpert.com/blog/sqlite_blob_time/) I found explaining how I can achieve what I am looking for, but still did not work with me.

here is my code I hope it is clear and you can understand it

```
@app.route('/createPost', methods=['POST'])
    def create_post():
         # this file came from an HTML form with POST method and it works
         # and the image save in here as FileStorage
        image = request.files['file'].read()
        g.db.execute("INSERT INTO Post(UserID, Link, Title, Notes, Category, Image)\
                     VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?);", (session['userID'],
                                             request.form['linkURL'],
                                             request.form['blocTitle'],
                                             request.form['notes'],
                                             request.form['category'],
                                             sqlite.Binary(image))) 
        # image filed is a BLOB type in the database so i can store binary
        g.db.commit()
        return "Post Created Sucssfully!"
```

I know how to save an image in a file in my website root folder I prefer to save in database so i could access the image easily with post so whenever I retrieve the post I can find the image and no need to access to the website folder

If you need any clarification about my question please ask
The code work perfectly and all the data saved in the database except the image. and no error occurs

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: looks like you forgot to actually read the image data from the request

Comment: I have Done that still

Comment: Please post error with traceback or undesired results since *but still did not work with me* is not helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: The code work perfectly and all the data saved in the database except the image. so weird